# Magento theme preview in mobile device

Tags: magento, mobile, themes

I'd like to choose an exist Magento Theme for mobile device. 
so I try to find suitable themes at the following website :
http://themeforest.net/

Since those themes are not cheap, I can't buy it without UI preview. 
even though Themeforest provide "preview" option, I can only preview the website version. for example : http://themeforest.net/item/ultimo-fluid-responsive-magento-theme/full_screen_preview/3231798

in other words, even I preview the page via "iPad" or "iPhone" mobile device , I still get the website version of Magento Theme UI

is there any way to preview Magento UI on mobile device before buying it?

Answer (score 0):

Simply open the preview on ThemeForest, disable ThemeForest frame (button [X] is at the top of the page on that black stripe). Then make your browser window narrower to see how the theme will look like on narrow screens.

Or use tools like this, they can be helpful:

http://mattkersley.com/responsive/ 
http://designwoop.com/2012/04/tools-for-testing-responsive-web-design/